# Regex FindAll not printing results Kotlin

Tags: regex, kotlin

I have a program that is using ML Kit to use Text recognition on a document and I am taking that data and only printing the prices. So I am taking the Text Recognition String and passing it through the regex below:

```
val reg = Regex("\$([0-9]*.[0-9]{2})")
    val matches = reg.findAll(rec)
    val prices = matches.map{it.groupValues[0]}.joinToString()
recogResult.text = prices
```

I have tested the Regex formula on another website and it grabs all the right data. However it is printing nothing. When it gets to the reg.findAll(rec) part matches = **kotlin.sequences.GeneratorSequence@bd56ff3** and prices = "".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```kotlin
val reg = Regex("""\$[0-9]*\.[0-9]{2}""")
val matches = reg.findAll("Price: \$1234.56 and \$1.56")
val prices = matches.map{it.groupValues[0]}.joinToString()
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/LG1auj). *Notes*:

- `"""..."""` is a triple quoted string literal where backslashes are parsed as literal `\` chars and are not used to form string escape sequences
- `\$` - in a triple quoted string literal defines a `\$` regex escape that matches a literal `$` char
- `[0-9]*\.[0-9]{2}` matches zero or more digits, `.` and two digits.

Note that you may use `\p{Sc}` to match any currency chars, not just `$`.

If you want to make sure no other digit follows the two fractional digits, add `(?![0-9])` at the end of your regex.